# easy-install with Portable Python: no module named parse

Tags: python, pandas, easy-install, portable-python

I have installed easy_install with Portable Python 2-7 on Windows XP (through the distribute module). But when I type a DOS command such as

```
easy_install pandas
```

I get the following: 
[image]

And I don't find any "parse" module on internet (and "easy_install parse" yields the same output)

Comment: urllib.parse is a python3 module, so either `pandas` doesn't support python 2.x or the 2to3 tool is being ran on the source code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is about the module `urllib.parse`, not `parse`. The documentation of the [urlparse module](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) says:

> The urlparse module is renamed to urllib.parse in Python 3.

which means your code expects to be run with Python 3. You are running Python 2.7 which means it won't work (because the module `urllib.parse` is still called `urlparse`). Perhaps you need to look into installing a version of Portable Python that supports Python 3?

Comment: Thank you. But I have just moved from Portable Python 3 to Portable Python 2 because I also have difficulties to install modules with Python 3 and there are more preinstalled modules in Python 2...